# Why wasn't there a communication delay when Neil Armstrong landed on the moon?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, communication

My understanding is that there was supposed to be a delay between the communication from the moon to Earth. Why were the communication instantaneous?

Comment: The delay is about 1.25 seconds each way. What makes you think it was instantaneous?

Comment: I don't suppose you're asking about a "tape" delay (as used in TV broadcasting for censorship purposes)...? Would have been a political landmine to implement such a thing.

Comment: This question shows a lack of research and is based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: I suppose it was instantaneous because it was faked :-)

Comment: They weren't @Kaomi Matos

Answer (score 14):

The delay for Earth-Moon communications is about 1.25 second (distance is ~ 380,000 km, the speed of light is ~300,000 km/s). You'd notice this delay only in conversations: every time ground control says something, it takes 2 seconds for the astronauts to respond.

In [videos of the live broadcast](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=apollo%2011%20live%20ABC) (search for 'Apollo 11 live ABC') you can hear the delay: ground control says "go for depressurization", then you hear the echo of that coming back from the Moon, and the astronauts' response.

Comment: yay, thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 13):

Some modern presentations of the moon landing will edit out the gaps created by the communication delay to make conversation sound more natural, but if you look at the [timestamped transcripts](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11transcript_tec.html), you can verify the 2.5 second round trip delay. Note that the timestamps all refer to the time the Earth-side recording occurred, so the radio delay appears when one of the crew members (CMP, CDR, LMP in the transcript) is responding to the Capcom (CC).